# post data in server api using javascript

Tags: javascript, json, rest

Hi I am very new to javascript and would like to ask how to post data in server api using javascript because when I click the button it won't save and does not return any error I am folowing this code here https://github.com/devamaz/fetchAPI/blob/master/index.html here is my js code:

```
function postData(event){
    event.preventDefault();

    let bookedUser = document.getElementById('bookedUser').value;
    let bookedUserName = document.getElementById('bookedUserName').value;
    let bookedEmail = document.getElementById('bookedEmail').value;
    let dateBooked = document.getElementById('dateBooked').value;
    let startTime = document.getElementById('startTime').value;
    let endTime = document.getElementById('endTime').value;
    let attendeesEmail = document.getElementById('attendeesEmail[]').value;
    let bookingDesc = document.getElementById('bookingDesc').value;

    fetch('http://localhost:8080/api/createBooking', {
        method: 'POST',
        headers : new Headers(),
        body: JSON.stringify({ 
            "bookedUser": bookedUser, 
            "bookedUserName": bookedUserName, 
            "bookedEmail":bookedEmail, 
            "dateBooked":dateBooked, 
            "startTime":startTime, 
            "endTime":endTime, 
            "attendeesEmail":attendeesEmail, 
            "bookingDesc":bookingDesc})
    }).then((res) => res.json())
        .then((booking) => alert('Data Sent'))
        .catch((err)=>console.log(err))
}
```

and here is the html:

```
    <form  id="postData">
        <div>
            <input type="text" placeholder="Booked User" id="bookedUser">
        </div>
        <div>
            <input type="text" placeholder="Username" id="bookedUserName">
        </div>
        <div>
            <input type="text" placeholder="Email" id="bookedEmail">
        </div>
        <div>
            <input type="date" placeholder="Date Booked" id="dateBooked">
        </div>
        <div>
            <input type="time" placeholder="Start time" id="startTime">
        </div>
        <div>
            <input type="time" placeholder="End time" id="endTime">
        </div>
        <div>
            <input type="text" placeholder="Attendees Email" id="attendeesEmail[]">
        </div>
        <div>
            <textarea id="bookingDesc" cols="20" rows="5"></textarea>
        </div>
        <input type="submit" value="SEND POST" onclick="postData();">
    </form>
```

I have tested the code in the backend using postman and it works fine, Thank you in advance

Comment: You should add `headers: { 'Content-type': 'application/json' }` instead of an empty `Headers` object

Comment: You're not passing the `event` object to `postData`. I would be very surprised if there weren't errors in your browser console. You should also monitor the _Network_ console to see what's happening with your request

Comment: @Phil Ok I'll check thank you

Comment: The error now is 404 and can you pls explain to me why I need to add "headers: { 'Content-type': 'application/json' }" this I'm very new to consuming api sorry about this.

Comment: 404 means your URL is incorrect. When posting data via HTTP, you should tell the remote service what format the request body is in via the `Content-type` header. When sending JSON (as you are) the `Content-type` should be `application/json`

Comment: @Phil Ok thank you for the explanation but I double checked the url and it is correct it matched the url I'm using on postman but the error is still 404 and I double checked the server if its running or not and it is running

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is almost all right. Just add the event param in postData() function.
Actually, there is no function postData() with no params.

So, it should be:

```
 <input type="submit" value="SEND POST" onclick="postData(event);">
```